# Non-localhost server: Managing root directory to maintain short url

Tags: php, symfony, url, web, server

For example, I have this domain `mamgrow.lt` and to reach main page I have to go `mamgrow.lt/web/` (because I am using Symfony2 framework).

The structure of directories and files in my server:

```
public_html:
    //here starts symfony files
    app:
    web:
        app.php
        app_dev.php
        .htaccess
    src:
    vendor:
```

This `.htaccess` file in web directory already maps `mamgrow.lt/web/` to `mamgrow.lt/web/app.dev/` which already makes url shorter.

Now to get rid of `/web/` for example in `localhost` servers like xampp uses Apache `VirtualHost` to change `Root Directory`, but how can I manage it in `non-localhost` online server? Should I create extra `.htaccess` in public_html directory, or edit the one in `web/`? Or is there any other way to change root directory to maintain short url like "mamgrow.lt/"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should place your project a directory up from `public_html`, and your web directory should become `public_html`.

Then you should have:

```
app:
src:
vendor:
public_html:
    app.php
    .htaccess
```

Note that if you are using Assetic, you have to configure it to use `public_html` instead of web:

```
# app/config/config.yml

# ...
assetic:
    # ...
    read_from: "%kernel.root_dir%/../../public_html"
```

Comment: Is it really practical for symfony project and the only way to manage this? Maybe there is a documentation I couldn't find?

Comment: It's actually mentioned in the docs: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/override_dir_structure.html#override-the-web-directory